# What is the difference between camera.transform and eulerAngles in ARKit?

Tags: ios, transform, arkit, euler-angles

According to the ARKit document, i.e., [ARCamera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera?language=objc), I see there are 2 ways describing the orientation of the camera, [camera.transform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2866108-transform?language=objc) and [eulerAngles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2866109-eulerangles?language=objc). First, I transform the rotation matrix of `frame.camera` to euler angles and then the outputs are not equal to `eulerAngle` values.

Why? What is the difference between `camera.transform` and `eulerAngle` values in ARKit?

The details of the transformation are described as follows.

Use the function in Eigen library to obtain the euler angles, `Rx.eulerAngles(0, 1, 2)`, where `Rx` is the rotation matrix of `frame.camera.transform`.

For example:

```
frame.camera.transform:
Rx = 

[ -0.0443775,  -0.900017,   0.433589;

  0.998663, -0.0284454,   0.043167;

-0.0265174,   0.434925,   0.900076; ]
```

The outputs of `Rx.eulerAngles(0, 1, 2)` are `[ 3.09367, 2.69312, -1.52153]`

`eulerAngle` values are `[ -0.449955, -0.0294528, -1.60239]`

Answer (score 0):

The Transform gives you information about the position, angles and scale of a node, the Euler angles only tell you about the angles, ie pitch roll and yaw.